# Noindex, nofollow stuck on homepage

Tags: search, search-engines, privacy

Recently my hosting automatically upgraded our Wordpress version. Due to custom plugin conflicts, we requested them to restore it to the previous version.

Our homepage now contains the code "meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' /" (< removed). From Googling, it appears that this code should be added when I visit the Privacy section of Wordpress and select "I would like to block search engines, but allow normal visitors".

However, my site is selected as "I would like my site to be visible to everyone, including search engines (like Google, Bing, Technorati) and archivers".

I also understand that by default, Wordpress chooses the first option, blocking search engines. I think that at some point during the restore to a previous version, Wordpress has got stuck in the blocking search engine mode. Changing privacy is having no affect on the code.

I need a manual way to remove "meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' /" from the homepage - I have no idea where the code is located though.

Comment: Try header.php in your theme file.

Answer (score 4):

The setting is stored in the options table under the key `blog_public`, the value is either `0` or `1`. You can see the value of all options by manually visiting the page `/wp-admin/options.php`.

A quick way to get rid of it would be to remove the `noindex` action hooked to `wp_head`, which is what outputs that tag if `blog_public` is `0`:

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'noindex', 1 );
```

This behavior is a bit strange though, I suspect perhaps something else may be involved here beyond simply the value of this option.

Comment: blog_public is 1.

Comment: try adding the `remove_action` bit to your theme's `functions.php`

Comment: In any particular section of functions.php, or just at the end?

Comment: at the end is fine. you can also try getting the value of the option directly in a template file to check if that also gives you `1`, or perhaps something is filtering the result: `echo get_option( 'blog_public' );`

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to do that. Where do I enter the echo? In a php file? I have never done that before.

Comment: Adding the code to the functions file appears to have made no difference. Homepage still references noindex and nofollow.

Comment: Another update: I failed and added the code to the wrong functions file. I added it to the correct file and the noindex, nofollow present at the top of the source code has now gone - Yay!  
However, there is a second instance, directly after the Platinum SEO Pack:  
<!-- platinum seo pack 1.3.7 -->
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
<!-- /platinum one seo pack -->
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />

Comment: Have you checked that plugins options? Was that present before you added the action which removed the first instance?

Comment: Yes, it was present before. The plugin has options to noindex the homepage, however they are not and never have been selected.

Comment: Well it's now 2016 and this still seems to be an issue. Trying the functions.php fix mentioned above. It seems like the Yoast SEO plugin is the cultprit in my case.

Comment: Plugins or themes can overwrite the `blog_public` value through the `pre_option_blog_public` hook. E.g. `add_action('pre_option_blog_public', '__return_zero');`. The mu-plugin 'disallow-indexing.php' does this for Bedrock (by roots.io) in non-production environments.